# jQuery Image Upload Error for Medium-Editor-Insert-Plugin

Tags: jquery, flask, image-uploading

I'm working with https://github.com/yabwe/medium-editor text-editor and I struggle in particular with its extension https://github.com/orthes/medium-editor-insert-plugin.

**My backend is Python-Flask**

The issue is that I'm getting is this error:

> medium-editor-insert-plugin.js:1940 --  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of undefined

This is the method which throws an error:

```
/**
 * Callback for successful upload requests.
 * https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#done
 *
 * @param {Event} e
 * @param {object} data
 * @return {void}
 */

Images.prototype.uploadDone = function (e, data) {
    $.proxy(this, 'showImage', data.result.files[0].url, data)();

    this.core.clean();
    this.sorting();
};
```

This is jQuery code on my client-side end:

```
var editor = new MediumEditor('.forecast-textarea__editor');

      $(function () {
        $('.forecast-textarea__editor').mediumInsert({
          editor: editor,
          addons: {
            images: {
              uploadScript: null,
              deleteScript: null,
              captionPlaceholder: 'Type caption for image',
              styles: {
                slideshow: {
                  label: '<span class="fa fa-play"></span>',
                  added: function ($el) {
                    $el
                      .data('cycle-center-vert', true)
                      .cycle({
                        slides: 'figure'
                      });
                  },
                  removed: function ($el) {
                    $el.cycle('destroy');
                  }
                }
              },
              actions: null,
              fileUploadOptions: { // (object) File upload configuration. See https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options
                url: '/upload_image', // (string) A relative path to an upload script
                acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpeg|jpg|png)$/i // (regexp) Regexp of accepted file types
              }
            }
          }
        })
      });
```

This is the backend method which answers the AJAX call:

```
@bp.route('/upload_image', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def upload_image():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        files = request.files
        print files
    print 'hello world, you"re uploading image right NOWWNOWNWOW'
    return ('', 204)
```

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Images.prototype.uploadDone` will run when the upload is done, It expects a JSON with a list in it named `files` as endpoint response, each file in this `files` list has a URL.

For now you are returning a blank response with status code 204,
You can use `jsonify` to generate a JSON response or you can completely ignore that error.

**JSONify Example**

```
@bp.route('/upload_image', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def upload_image():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        files = request.files
        print files
    print 'hello world, you"re uploading image right NOWWNOWNWOW'
    return jsonify(files=[{url='', fileName='Something'}, ]), 204
```

Here is an example of `jsonify` with static Data where url of first element is blank and fileName of first element is Something in a list named tuple, This should work fine!

If you want to generate dynamic `jsonify` responses you may want to read this link from documentation => http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.json.jsonify

Comment: Oh great... thank you... Just a question... Why does it expect the json with url? More precisely, where does the URL information come in handy?

Comment: The first question, this is how medium-editor-insert-plugin works, The second question, when u want to use them, I dont know the use case on your project, but for example, let's say u uploaded a picture, cut it in 2 sizes, one full size, second thumbnail, u use one endpoint and handle the usage on frontend with some statement like if its a photo in sidebar, use the thumbnail size, if its in the post page, use the fullsize and stuff.. the data is what u send using your backend.. so it can be customized for your use case